# WinUI 3 Datagrid Checkbox not Bound when using Template Column and Cell/Data Template

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

There is what I'd consider a bug, or at least a design problem, with the WinAppSDK datagrid checkbox. It requires multiple clicks to select and feels very glitchy.  It's unacceptable as a user experience, so I was required to find a workaround, which I did here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4b96bee6-dc19-4622-9de7-93ad0dbb6df1/want-to-reduce-number-of-clicks-require-to-check-microsoftwindowsdatagridcheckboxcolumn?forum=wpf

The problem is, the checkbox does not appear to bind at all. The datagrid below has two columns, the first uses the checkbox solution, allowing for an acceptable UI experience, and the second uses a standard checkbox column. The first column is not binding correctly (no change to  `ViewModel.TestSource.Selected` for the row), while the second column DOES bind correctly.

What am I missing in regard to binding the first column?

Note—the example doesn't have `UpdateSourceTrigger` set in the column, but this never seems to do anything since it is set for the datagrid.

```xml
<controls:DataGrid
    x:Name="TestDatagrud"
    Margin="12"
    GridLinesVisibility="All"
    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="PowderBlue"
    VerticalGridLinesBrush="PowderBlue"
    BorderBrush="PowderBlue"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.TestSource, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test 01">
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Selected}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <controls:DataGridCheckBoxColumn
            IsReadOnly="False"
            Header="Test 02"
            Width="75"
            Binding="{Binding Selected}" />
    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the change back to the source, in this case **ViewModel.TestSource.Selected**, you need to use `TwoWay` mode.

```xml
IsChecked="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Let me also mention that you can use `x:Bind` here.

```xml
<!-- Assuming that the type is Item. -->
<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
    <CheckBox
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        IsChecked="{x:Bind Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I had already tried adding twoway mode and an updatesourcetrigger. Didn't do a thing. Using X:DataType and X:Bind in your bottom example is a little generic for me to interpret., the data is bound to the ViewModel class per the binding of the overall datagrid in my example. Is there a way to bind the data template/ check box to that?

Comment: It should work. Can you post more related code? Especially code around your ViewModel and the Selected property.